# Playground not working

Tags: ios, xcode7

I can't use playground. It shows this error : Playground execution terminated because the process stopped unexpectedly.

All I did was installing iOS 9 simulator by downloading it with terminal and copying it manually to where it was supposed to be and clicking download on preferences to install the downloaded file because I was not able to download it normally.

In other topics my problem was mentioned and the solution was restarting Xcode and mac, I even removed Xcode and reinstalled it using a dmg file instead of installing it by mac App Store which I used to. I tried it and I still have the issue. (My Xcode is not a beta version.) Is it just me in this whole mac community who has this problem and there is no solution ?!

Thanks

Comment: I've had the same problem; also tried reinstalling Xcode and restarting my Mac etc, to no avail. Please post if you manage to resolve this.

Comment: @Jason My problem was not exactly solved, but I can use playground for now. After the last time I re-installed Xcode using the .dmg file it was somehow fixed, but I faced the problem once again couple of days ago. It comes and goes this time, still not sure about the permanent solution. Hope somebody comes up with a solution.